# Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Folder is not using SocketChannels

Tags: jakarta-mail

Using idle manager this exception appears:
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Folder is not using SocketChannels

How can i solve this problem ?

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
final IdleManager idleManager = new IdleManager(session, es);


folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            folder.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountAdapter() {
                public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent ev) {
             Folder folder = (Folder)ev.getSource();
             Message[] msgs = ev.getMessages();
             System.out.println("Folder: " + folder +
                 " got " + msgs.length + " new messages");
                    try {
                        // process new messages
                        System.out.println("***********************process new messages : ");

                        idleManager.watch(folder); // keep watching for new messages
                    } catch (IOException | MessagingException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(mail2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            });

            idleManager.watch(folder);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [IdleManager javadocs](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IdleManager.html) say:

> .. set the mail.imap.usesocketchannels property in the Session

Comment: just add   props.setProperty("mail.imaps.usesocketchannels", "true");

Comment: after 30 minutes a folder closed exception appears, the idle Manager handle it and restart idling but don't restart treating the emails. Can you help me please ?

Comment: What does the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

Comment: Debug IMAP: IdleManager waiting ...          if i send a test mail, no reaction appears.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void watch_mail(Folder folder) throws IOException, MessagingException, InterruptedException {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("hi, interrupted = " + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
                    folder.getMessageCount();
                    idleManager.watch(folder);
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(30000);
                } catch (MessagingException | InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(listening_test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    folder.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountAdapter() {
        public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent ev) {
            Folder folder = (Folder) ev.getSource();
            Message[] msgs = ev.getMessages();
            System.out.println("Folder: " + folder
                    + " got " + msgs.length + " new messages");
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                try {
                    // Get dates date 1 (day_month_year) and date 2(hours:min:second)
                    String dates[] = getDates(msgs[i]);
                    System.out.println("*************date 1: " + dates[0]);
                    System.out.println("*************date 2: " + dates[1]);
                    idleManager.watch(folder);

                } catch (ParseException | MessagingException | IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(listening_test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}

hi, interrupted = false
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager watching INBOX
A4 IDLE
+ idling
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 0 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager adding INBOX to selector
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
hi, interrupted = false
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 0 channels
```

Comment: (You really should add additional information to your question, not as an answer.)  It's normal for the server to drop the connection after 30 minutes if you're not using it, and the IdleManager doesn't try to override that.  If you want to keep the connection alive even though you're not actually using it, you'll need to periodically do something like call Folder.getMessageCount to "poke" the server and make it think you're still using the connection.

Comment: (sorry about the answer.) How can i "poke" the server ?  every time i call the Folder.getMessageCount, the idleManager stop idling. it pass from "DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting..." to "DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 0 channels" and it don't treat new mails any more.

Comment: Well of course you have to call IdleManager.watch afterwards.

Comment: ok this is what i'm trying to do but without success. Can you please provide an example. thank you

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an example.  Update your post with the code you're using and the debug output you get when running that code.

Comment: any success on the problem? Did Folder.getMessageCount and then IdleManager.watch afterwards resolved the problem?