# javamail exception: javax.mail.MessagingException: Folder is not using SocketChannels

Tags: android, exception, jakarta-mail

When i use idle manager,i got this exception.
Of cause I have viewed this answer[[Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Folder is not using SocketChannels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33389719/exception-in-thread-main-javax-mail-messagingexception-folder-is-not-using-so][1])

and I tryed

> properties.setProperty("mail.imap.usesocketchannels", "true");

But it doesn't work with my code,and still appeared this exception.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.imap.host", mailReceiveServer);
    properties.put("mail.imap.auth", validate ? "true" : "false");
    properties.put("mail.imap.port", mailReceivePort);
    properties.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.imap.partialfetch", false);
    properties.put("mail.event.scope", "session");

    properties.put("mail.imap.ssl.checkserveridentity", "false");
    properties.put("mail.imap.ssl.trust", "*");
    properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
    properties.put("mail.event.executor", es);
    properties.setProperty("mail.imap.usesocketchannels", "true");
```

Is there any wrong with my properties?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to change `imap` to `imaps` as stated in the comments of the linked answer?

Comment: And make sure you haven't made any of these other [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).

Comment: Thank all of you! I tried either imap or imaps and I got the same exception.I'll refer to the FAQ and samples carefully.

Comment: @BillShannon I have checked my code that I use `Session.getInstance()` rather than use `Session.getDefaultInstance()`.And actually I haven't use any `socketFactory` in properties.By the way,I use javamail 1.5.6 in Android right now. It's best that if you can provide a correct `properties`.Thank you very much!

Comment: What does the JavaMail debug output show?

Comment: @BillShannon I have post output in the answer as a picture.Thanks for your attention!

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong in the property settings or debug output.  When you call the IdleManager.watch method, is the Folder open?

Comment: @BillShannon I'm sure that the Folder is open at that time.

Comment: I give up.  Do you have a reproducible test case?  Does it fail if you run it with real Java instead of Android?

Comment: @BillShannon It's sad that I have ran it with real Java and got the same exception.I also tried with javamail 1.6.0 what is designed for android and still didn't work correctly.

Comment: Great, show me the code for your reproducible test case.  If you don't want to post it here, send it to me at javamail_ww@oracle.com.

Comment: @BillShannon Well,I have send an email to you with test case code.Thank you!

Comment: Let @BillShannon know if would be willing to test a JakartaMail code fix that we are working on for this issue under Android.  We would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be related to [Issue 403- Android SocketChannel workaround not working around](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mail/issues/403).

By default the Android implementation for secure sockets doesn't return a socket channel.  Previous releases of JavaMail use reflection to access the socket and create the channel.  Later, Android was updated to to use [Conscrypt](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/modular-system/conscrypt) to provide SSL sockets.  It too doesn't return a socket channel however, the existing JavaMail workaround doesn't work because the wrapped socket is in a deeper subclass which JavaMail was not expecting.

The fix applied to [JavaMail 1.6.6](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mail/commit/50ea97d82a7897b5470de8d19c58ba0ce4e0cc0b#diff-c798b1f37720e01837f9391eca856c816479bd7699f24f0b3eb9959b2e311854), [JakartaMail 2.0.1](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mail/blob/4b4b44b37aa348365edcf80e54ae5a04f00a2e45/doc/release/CHANGES.txt#L27), and Jakarta EE 9.1.  Upgrading to those versions should correct the issue you are seeing.