# Folder is not using SocketChannels

Tags: java, kotlin, jakarta-mail

I have the following code:

```
typealias MessagePredicate = (Message) -> Boolean
object EmailHelper {
    private val session: Session by lazy {
        val props = System.getProperties()
        props["mail.imaps.usesocketchannels"] = "true"
        props["mail.imap.usesocketchannels"] = "true"
        Session.getInstance(props, null)
    }
    private val store = session.getStore("gimap") as GmailStore
    private val idleManager = IdleManager(session, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
    private val folder: GmailFolder by lazy { store.getFolder("INBOX") as GmailFolder }


    init {
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "***@gmail.com", "***")
        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY)
        idleManager.watch(folder)
    }

    fun watchForMessage(condition: MessagePredicate): CompletableFuture<Message> {
        val promise = CompletableFuture<Message>()
        folder.addMessageCountListener(object : MessageCountAdapter() {
            override fun messagesAdded(e: MessageCountEvent) {
                super.messagesAdded(e)
                e.messages.firstOrNull(condition)?.let {
                    folder.removeMessageCountListener(this)
                    promise.complete(it)
                }
            }
        })
        return promise
    }

}
```

However when I run this code I'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.muliyul.MainKt.main(Main.kt:28)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Folder is not using SocketChannels
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IdleManager.watch(IdleManager.java:205)
    at com.muliyul.EmailHelper.<clinit>(EmailHelper.kt:40)
    ... 1 more
```

I am setting the property "mail.imaps.usesocketchannels" beforehand and I've also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346936/javamail-exception-javax-mail-messagingexception-folder-is-not-using-socketcha) question yet I can't wrap my head around what's wrong with my code.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Side note: the email provider is Gmail (obviously).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An hour after I posted this question (and 3 hours of researching) I finally found an answer.

You have to set the property `mail.gimap.usesocketchannels` to `"true"` (and not `mail.imap.usesocketchannels` or `mail.imaps.usesocketchannels`)

This is due to the fact that `gimap` is a different protocol than `imap`.

There goes 3 hours down the drain.

Comment: And I assume you're using gimap because you need to use some gimap-specific feature, even though the code above doesn't need it.  Otherwise, you could've just used the imap protocol.

Comment: Correct Bill. I'm doing server side filtering with GmailRawTerm.